# How I stop my auto rorated slider on click of link for 10 sec?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Facing problem to stop my auto rotated slider on click of above link.
My auto rotated slider is working fine even if i click on above link like car, car1 etc so its perfectly target its reference image but I tried stop at least 10 sec on clicked link but not getting success :(

Link is http://karanbhilware.com/mail_send/demo2.html

Here is the jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var carSpecifications = $('.Specifications li'),
        carSpecificationsCount = 1,
        specificationsGallery = $('#specificationsGallery li'),
        galleryLast = specificationsGallery.last(),
        specificationsGalleryCount = 1,
        galleryLen = carSpecifications.length,
        galleryLen2 = galleryLen - 1;
    current = 1;

    carSpecifications.each(function () {
        $(this).attr('class', 'Specifications_' + carSpecificationsCount++);
    });
    specificationsGallery.each(function () {
        $(this).attr('id', 'gallery_' + specificationsGalleryCount++);
    });
    var galLastId = galleryLast.attr('id'),
        galLastNum = galLastId.split('_');
    console.log(galleryLen2);
    console.log(galleryLen);

    specificationsGallery.fadeOut();
    specificationsGallery.first().fadeIn().addClass('active');

    console.log(galleryLast);

    function Specifications() {

        $('#specificationsGallery').find('.active')
            .next('li').fadeIn(1000).addClass('active')
            .prev('li').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active');

        var test = $('#specificationsGallery .active').index();
        console.log(test);
        if (galleryLen2 === test) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                galleryLast.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active');
                specificationsGallery.first().fadeIn().addClass('active').delay(800);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }

    carSpecifications.on('click', function () {
        var SpecificationsSplit = $(this).attr('class'),
            splitId = SpecificationsSplit.split('_')
        //$('li[id^="gallery_"]').removeClass('active');
        //var test = $('#gallery_'+splitId[1]).addClass('active');
        $('li[id^="gallery_"]').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
        var test = $('#gallery_' + splitId[1]).fadeIn().addClass('active');
    });

    setInterval(Specifications, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your interval is running every 5 seconds no matter what. I don't see any real code to cancel it.

You need to cancel the timer when it gets clicked, and then re-enable it 10 seconds later. You can use [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) for that. It takes an interval ID (returned from `setInterval()`), so you need to save that as well.

See the snippet below for some actual code examples.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var carSpecifications = $('.Specifications li'),
    carSpecificationsCount = 1,
    specificationsGallery = $('#specificationsGallery li'),
    galleryLast = specificationsGallery.last(),
    specificationsGalleryCount = 1,
    galleryLen = carSpecifications.length,
    galleryLen2 = galleryLen - 1,
    current = 1,
    interval;

  carSpecifications.each(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'Specifications_' + carSpecificationsCount++);
  });
  specificationsGallery.each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', 'gallery_' + specificationsGalleryCount++);
  });
  var galLastId = galleryLast.attr('id'),
    galLastNum = galLastId.split('_');
  //test = $('#specificationsGallery li.active');
  console.log(galleryLen2);
  console.log(galleryLen);

  //if(test === ) 




  specificationsGallery.fadeOut();
  specificationsGallery.first().fadeIn().addClass('active');

  console.log(galleryLast);


  function Specifications() {

    $('#specificationsGallery').find('.active').next('li').fadeIn(1000).addClass('active').prev('li').fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active');

    var test = $('#specificationsGallery .active').index();
    console.log(test);
    if (galleryLen2 === test) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        galleryLast.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('active');
        specificationsGallery.first().fadeIn().addClass('active').delay(800);
      }, 5000);

    }
  }
  carSpecifications.on('click', function() {
    var SpecificationsSplit = $(this).attr('class'),
      splitId = SpecificationsSplit.split('_')
      //$('li[id^="gallery_"]').removeClass('active');
      //var test = $('#gallery_'+splitId[1]).addClass('active');
    $('li[id^="gallery_"]').fadeOut().removeClass('active');
    var test = $('#gallery_' + splitId[1]).fadeIn().addClass('active');
    clearInterval(interval);
    setTimeout(function() {
      interval = setInterval(Specifications, 5000);
    }, 10000);
  });


  function hello(stopSl) {
    clearInterval(Specifications);
  }
  interval = setInterval(Specifications, 5000);
});
```

```css
#carVscarDes,#carVscarDes li img{width:500px;height:500px}#specificationsGallery,li{float:left}ul{clear:both}li{list-style:none;padding:10px}#carVscar li{padding:5px}#carVscar li.active{border:1px solid red}#carVscarDes{float:left;overflow:hidden;position:relative}#carVscarDes li{position:absolute;right:-100%;transition:all .4s ease;opacity:0}#carVscarDes li.active{opacity:1;right:0}#specificationsGallery li{position:absolute;z-index:1}#specificationsGallery li.active{z-index:2}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<base href="http://karanbhilware.com/mail_send/demo2.html"/>
<ul class="Specifications">
  <li>car</li>
  <li>car 2</li>
  <li>car 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="Specifications">
  <li>car 4</li>
  <li>car 5</li>
  <li>car 6</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div>
  <ul id="specificationsGallery">
    <li>
      <img src="images/1.jpg" width="950" height="350" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/2.jpg" width="950" height="350" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/3.jpg" width="950" height="350" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/4.jpg" width="950" height="350" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/5.jpg" width="950" height="350" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/3.jpg" width="950" height="350" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```